# How to check in a table if a column has a certain value?

Tags: postgresql

I need help with a query in postgress , i am trying to check if a column has a value or not and to do an insert

I have two databases on local and on is in server 
and in this table ccpt_data.user_role_permission in column user_role_name I have permission :

```
Locally I have this query and works :
   INSERT INTO ccpt_data.user_role_permission(user_role_name, permission_name)
    VALUES ('manager','MANAGE_SENSITIVE_DATA');

For the server will be something 
INSERT INTO ccpt_data.user_role_permission(user_role_name, permission_name)
VALUES ('ROLE_PROJECT_MANAGER','MANAGE_SENSITIVE_DATA');
```

But I can't do it like this so I need if-else condition, to check for example
if at ccpt_data.user_role_permission in user_role_name has a manager than I will do this and else the other this, so i am trying on something but as I don't know Postgres I need some help.
I am trying :

```
DO
$do$
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT  FROM ccpt_data.user_role_permission Where user_role_name = manager ) THEN
INSERT INTO ccpt_data.user_role_permission(user_role_name, permission_name)
VALUES ('ROLE_PROJECT_MANAGER','MANAGE_SENSITIVE_DATA');
ELSE 
   INSERT INTO ccpt_data.user_role_permission(user_role_name, permission_name)
    VALUES ('manager','MANAGE_SENSITIVE_DATA');
END IF;
END
$do$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you said is a `upsert` function, it can be implemented by CTE(with clause) in PostgreSQL.As below:

```
select * from test;
 id | result 
----+--------
  1 | data1
(1 row)

with upsert as (
update test set result='data10' where id=3 returning *
)
insert into test select 3,'data10' where not exists (select 1 from upsert where id = 3);
INSERT 0 1

select * from test;
 id | result 
----+--------
  1 | data1
  3 | data10
(2 rows)

with upsert as (
update test set result='data22' where id=3 returning *
)
insert into test select 3,'data22' where not exists (select 1 from upsert where id = 3);
INSERT 0 0

select * from test;
 id | result 
----+--------
  1 | data1
  3 | data22
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what's wrong with what you have, other than missing something between `SELECT` and `FROM` and that you need to put `manager` in quotes. It should work.

But if you want to avoid procedural code you can use a `CASE` expression returning `'ROLE_PROJECT_MANAGER'` if `'manager'` exists and `'manager'` otherwise.

For example in an `INSERT ... SELECT ...` (but it should also work to put it in a `VALUES` clause if you prefer that):

```
INSERT INTO ccpt_data.user_role_permission
            (user_role_name,
             permission_name)
            SELECT CASE
                     WHEN EXISTS (SELECT *
                                         FROM ccpt_data.user_role_permission
                                         WHERE user_role_name = 'manager') THEN
                       'ROLE_PROJECT_MANAGER'
                     ELSE
                       'manager'
                   END,
                   'MANAGE_SENSITIVE_DATA';
```

Comment: I just need the quotes I fixed already but thank you a lot, you teach me sth thanks